# Convert JTable data into UPDATE statement

Tags: java, sql

I want to be able to get the data from a JTable converted into a UPDATE statement so that I can get the table contents and use my existing SQL connection to transfer into DB.

eg

[image: Example data]

into

```
UPDATE Products SET ProductID="JUICE32", ProdName="Orange Juice", Stock=190, Price=8.00 WHERE ProductID="JUICE32";
UPDATE Products SET ProductID="SOAP123", ProdName="Deluxe Soap", Stock=500, Price=15.99 WHERE ProductID="SOAP123";
UPDATE Products SET ProductID="TOWEL12", ProdName="Towel", Stock=0, Price=25.50 WHERE ProductID="TOWEL12";
```

Note that I do not allow editing of Primary Key. This is intentional

Comment: on a side note: I won't accept my own answer for a while, at least until it gets more upvotes

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `PreparedStatment` to make the code easier to understand and maintain.

I'm not an SQL expert but the code would be something like:

```
String sql = "UPDATE Products SET ProductID = ?, ProdName = ?, Stock = ?, Price = ? WHERE ProductID = ?";

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.setString( 1, table.getValueAt(row, 0) );
stmt.setString( 2, table.getVAlueAt(row, 1) );
stmt.setInteger( 3, table.getVAlueAt(row, 2) );
stmt.setDouble( 4, table.getVAlueAt(row, 3) );
stmt.setString( 5, table.getValueAt(row, 0) );
stmt.executeUpdate();
stmt.close();
```

Hope you get the idea. You build the SQL statement using "?" for the variable data. Then you just set value of each "?". The `PreparedStatement` will worry about the proper formatting etc. A lot less prone to mistakes.

Also, I'm not sure why your code is setting the product id. I would have thought you only need to set the 3 values that change.

Edit:

To make the above even more generic you might do something like:

```
public void updateTable(JTable table)
{
    String sql = createSql(table);

    for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
        updateRow(sql, table, i);
    }
}


public String createSql(JTable table)
{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("UPDATE " + tableName + " SET ");

    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        sql.append(table.getColumnName(i) + " = ?";
        sql.append(i + 1 == table.getColumnCount() ? " " : ", ");
    }

    return sql.toString();
}

public void updateRow(String sql, JTable table int row)
{
    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

    for (int i = 0; i <table.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        stmt.setObject( i + 1, table.getValueAt(row, i) );
    }

    stmt.setObject(table.getColumnCount, table.getValueAt(row, i));
    stmt.executeUpdate();
    stmt.close();
}
```

Comment: Although your method should work just fine, mine allows for use on _any_ table, in yours you have to know the data types **beforehand**

Comment: `mine allows for use on any table` - the code can be modified to make it more generic, I was just introducing you to the PreparedStatement class. `my code only supports BigDecimal, String, Integer and Boolean types` that is why you should use the PreparedStatement, it supports all the data types and knows all the rules to make sure the SQL string is syntactically correct. You can use the "setObject(...)" method instead. Don't reinvent the wheel.  If you continue along your approach I would use a StringBuilder to build your SQL query instead of using String concatenation.

Comment: What is the advantage of StringBuilder? Also it is true, I am making something that is already there, but does PreparedStatement do detection? The reason I gave that comment is that your code `stmt.setString( 1, table.getValueAt(row, 0) );` requires knowing the types beforehand, as far as i can see, PreparedStatement does not let you detect. Would substituting the `update += JTable1.getValueAt(i, j);` in the switch with the appropriate PreparedStatement work?

Comment: @Kyle 1) already answer, String concatenation is not very efficient. 2) already answered, use setObject(...). 3) see edit.

Comment: I see, unfortunately I encountered an irritating "feature" in JTable: if I called `JTable1.getValueAt(0, 2j).getClass().getTypeName()//if my x,y is right` in order to get 190's type, it will return .Integer the first time, but if the cell is edited it will return .String... Had to make verification method using a List<Class> as reference getting values at population time

Comment: @Kyle `it will return .Integer the first time, but if the cell is edited it will return .String` - that has nothing to do with this question. That is a problem with your `TableModel`. You need to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method so the JTable can use the proper editor. Read the `JTable` API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables` for more information and examples.

Answer (score 1):

So far my code only supports BigDecimal, String, Integer and Boolean types, but it should be relatively easy to add more (look inside switch statement)

```
public String getUpdateStmt(JTable JTable1, String tableName)
{
    String update = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < JTable1.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
        update += "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET";
        for (int j = 0; j < JTable1.getColumnCount(); j++)
        {
            update += " " + JTable1.getColumnName(j) + "=";
            switch (JTable1.getValueAt(i, j).getClass().getTypeName())
            {
                case "java.lang.String":
                    update += "\"" + JTable1.getValueAt(i, j) + "\"";
                    break;
                case "java.math.BigDecimal": //all these don't need quotes etc
                case "java.lang.Integer":
                case "java.lang.Boolean":
                    update += JTable1.getValueAt(i, j);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.err.println(JTable1.getValueAt(i, j).getClass().getTypeName());
            }
            if (!(j + 1 == JTable1.getColumnCount()))//stops insertion of comma on last value
            {
                update += ",";
            }
        }
        update += " WHERE " + JTable1.getColumnName(0) + "=\"" + JTable1.getValueAt(i, 0) + "\"";//Where clause using primary key
        update += ";\n";//ends SQL statement
    }

    System.err.println(update); //debugging
    return update;
}
```

Use as normal in your `executeSQL(String stmt);` method

I just wanted to post my findings while doing a project. I have searched the internet for this and have found NO way to change a jtable into SQL.

*Please tell me of any improvement(s) that I can add, as I intend for this to help out many people*

Comment: This is a good start, however it would be better to only have bind variable placeholders (`?`) in the query literal which you'd feed into a `PreparedStatement`. The values you would assign separately using the datatype-specific setters of the statement. Doing this would fix the SQL injection problem which manifests when there is string data with quotes in the table.

Comment: That is true, will try it out and see results